# Find the width and height of the modal-message

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to increase the size of the width and height of the modal-message.

Please find the message example here.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Can anyone help me to find the location of the width and height?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

There are `width` and `height` options: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
.dialog({
    width: 420,
    height: 200,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initally set width and height here at [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width)

Answer (score 0):

from the example above you can do this to get the width and height of modal

```
$(".demo-frame").contents().find(".ui-dialog").width();
$(".demo-frame").contents().find(".ui-dialog").height();
```

you must be carefull because the model is inside a iframe.
and for that reason you should use `$(".demo-frame").contents()` to acess the modal
you can also pass change the width and height, passing the size you want:

```
 $(".demo-frame").contents().find(".ui-dialog").width("100px");
$(".demo-frame").contents().find(".ui-dialog").height("100px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the dialog with the height or width option specified:

```
$(".selector").dialog({ height: 400 });
```

Also, you can set the height or width option after initialization:

```
$(".selector").dialog( "option", "height", 400 );
```